# A question on ordinary differential inequality

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Could we find a solution $f=f(x)$ to the following initial problem for the OD inequality?
$$3xf'+f-\sqrt{6f}\leq 0,\quad f(0)=0,\quad f(8/3)=6.$$

.

---

Added: The above question is in fact a special case of the following question:

Could we find a solution $f=f(x)$ to the following initial problem for the OD inequality?
$$xf'+(u+1/6)f-2\sqrt{uf}\leq 0,\quad f(0)=0,\quad f(8/3)=6,$$
where $u$ is a to-be-determined function.

Comment: No, it's non-linear, and appears to be over specified and underspecified at the same time. Where did you get this from?

Comment: @Zach466920 It is an inequality, not an equation, why is it over specified and under specified?

Comment: This is non-linear D.E. of 1st order, so then how do you have two initial conditions?

Comment: I'm aware, I never referred to it as an equation. It's over specified, because you have two boundary conditions, it's underspecified because you'd need to provide proof that this ODI, ordinary differential inequality, has a unique solution, else I'd say $f(x)=0$ works.

Comment: @Zach466920 for example the ODE $f'=f$ with $f(0)=1, f(1)=e$ does have a solution.

Comment: This is an ODI correct? You'll have to prove that the over specification of boundary conditions has a solution, which can only be done if you add more information about solution conditions. I'd suggest a link or something.

Comment: @Zach466920 That's what I am asking for... whether it has a solution or not...

Comment: It doesn't have a solution as you've presented the problem. You generally can't have two boundary conditions on a first order ODI, and if you could on a specific example, you'd have to show us proof. Is that clear enough?

Comment: @Zach466920 I know that generally we cannot have two boundary conditions, but some special cases we can. My question is essentially that is my ODI of the special case or not, which I don't know how to prove it yet.

Answer (score 1):

By separation of variables of $$3x\frac{df}{dx}+f-\sqrt{6} \cdot \sqrt{f} \le 0$$ which implies that

$$3x\frac{df}{dx}\le\sqrt{6} \cdot \sqrt{f} -f$$

$$\Rightarrow 3xdf\le(\sqrt{6} \cdot \sqrt{f} -f)dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \int\frac{df}{\sqrt{6} \cdot \sqrt{f} -f}\le\int\frac{dx}{3x}$$

$$\Rightarrow -\frac{2}{\sqrt 6} \ln|1-\frac{\sqrt f}{\sqrt 6}| \le 3\ln x +C$$

$$\Rightarrow  \ln|1-\frac{\sqrt f}{\sqrt 6}|^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt 6}} \le \ln x^3+C$$
$$\Rightarrow  |1-\frac{\sqrt f}{\sqrt 6}|^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt 6}} \le e^C x^3$$

since $f(0) =0$, then on the right hand side we get $0$ and the left hand side is $1$ but $1$ is not less than $0$, so we deduce that there is no solution at $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But I do need $f(0)=0$ and I don't need equation but only inequality.

Comment: The solution I gave is for (**) when $=0$, to have $\le 0$ you just put the function $u$ less than the function i found. At $x=0$ I don't think it has a solution ... I'll try

Comment: see now I edit ..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.